# Click on some elements does not work on Firefox with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Clicking on some elements does not work on Firefox while it work without any issue with other browsers.

**Firefox driver configuration**

```
 if(browserName.equals("FF")) {
      
     System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", 
             prop.getProperty("FirefoxDriver_win64"));
     
   ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
   FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("automationprofile");
   
   FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions(); 
 
   DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
   capabilities.setVersion("84.0.1");
   capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
   capabilities.setCapability("marionette", false);
   capabilities.setCapability("moz:firefoxOptions", options);
      driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
 }
```

best regards,

Comment: What is the error thrown by the script? Do you see any element overlapping with the clicking elements when the test is executed ?

Comment: Hi Janesh , the problem is solved when i add moveToElement(locator) before clicking on it , i use waitForElementToBeClickable,  the error was element not clickable at point(x,y) !